# local storage value still return previous value after logout application or clearing local storage value

Tags: angular7

When i logged into my application as  a superuser user type 'superuser' stored in localstorage after successful login. But when i logged in as a admin user 'admin' usertype stored into localstorage & it will call the services which only accessible by superuser for the admin user.

### Login component where local storage item set as a userInfo key

```
this.commonService.login(loginData).subscribe(res => {   
  let encodeCode = AES.encrypt(res['user'].organizationId, myGlobals.ENC_KEY).toString();
      // if (res['user'].type == 'admin'){
      //   this.router.navigate(["../admin/organization/edit"], { queryParams: { id: encodeCode }, relativeTo: this.route });
      // } else {
        this.router.navigate([""]);
      // }  
      this.spinner.hide(); 
      Toast.fire({
        type: 'success',
        title: 'Logged in successfully'
      })    
      this.isError = false;
      localStorage.setItem('token', res['accessToken']);
      localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(res['user'])); 
      let defaultSet: any = { org: true, user: true, flow: true, conn: true };    
      localStorage.setItem("default", JSON.stringify(defaultSet));
    }, error => {
      this.isError = true;
    });
```

### Organization component where condition is set

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.searchValid();
    if (this.userType.type == 'superuser') {
      this.organizationList();
    } else {
      this.projectList();
    }
    $("#orgLink").addClass('active');
    // Initialize Socket
    if (myGlobals.SOCKET) {
      this.initSocket();
    } 
  }
```

Comment: localstorage has been retained by browser even you logout . you should use sessionstorage in this scenario.

Comment: Is there any other solution rather than sessionStorage?

Comment: Yes, You may use  your own cache or 3rd party cache(S)